# Delete un-wanted files from a folder based on file type

Tags: windows

I need help on finding a tool to delete certain files with a specific file types from a directory on Windows.

Lets say I have a folder with 500 files, 150 files with extension .pdf, and 350 with .exe. I want a tool to delete .exe files automatically whenever they appear inside the folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to automate this, you can use the Windows task scheduler.

Create a new task, and for the action, use

```
cmd.exe /c "del c:\folder\*.exe"
```

You can schedule this to run as frequently as you like.  If you need to do this immediately as an .exe gets saved, then you'll want to enable auditing on the folder, and trigger the scheduled task on an audit event.  I'll edit this and add it if this is important as it is quite involved.

Comment: Can we reverse this action to keep only .PDF & .txt files and delete every other file formats within the folder? This would be perfect.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this with a simple DOS command.  The command would be something like this.

```
DEL /S /Q c:\MyFolder\*.exe
```

This will delete all files that have the .exe extension from the folder C:\MyFolder, and all subdirectories. You can omit the /S part if you don't want to delete from sub-directories. If you want to automate this, you can set this up as a scheduled task and run it as often as necessary.  I won't be immediate in deleting the files, but if you run it frequently enough it should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you too. I can only mark one answer as a valid answer for my questions, and it got to be Pauls answer.

Comment: This answer is the better, once it has the subdir option. Thx!